# Formula to input data with reference to a date range

Tags: date, formula, openoffice-calc

Currently I am trying to come up with a leave tracking system using OpenOffice Calc, so I have two sheets of data:

sheet 1:

```
    s/n    name    date start    date end
    1      test    3 Jan 2012    3 Jan 2012  <- formatted to date format
    2      test    6 Jan 2012    8 Jan 2012
```

while sheet 2 should look like this after I add in the formula:

```
    name   3Jan  4Jan  5Jan  6Jan  7Jan  8Jan  <- formatted to date format
    test    1                 1     1     1
```

My problem is how to use a formula on the second sheet under the dates which would refer to sheet 1 and automatically add a `1` if the person is on leave on that day. The dates will give me a serial number if I were to get the value from the cell which I use to match the dates on sheet 1 and sheet 2.

Using VLOOKUP I was able to get the value of the date start and end in sheet 1 from sheet 2:

```
    =VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$D$3;3;0)
    =VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$D$3;4;0)
```

and then an IF statement to add a `1` or a `""`:

```
    =IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$D$3;3;0)=MID(B1;1;6);"1";"")
```

However I face a problem with this part with a leave of many days (example entry 2 in sheet 1 where the leave ranges from 6 - 8 Jan).

So I tried to compare the values if the date is greater than or equal to the start date and the date is less than or equal to the end date, but failed. This is the formula I tried:

```
    =IF(VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$D$3;3;0)>=MID(B1;1;6)<=VLOOKUP(A2;$A$2:$D$3;4;0);"1";"")
```

Can anyone can help me with this issue or have any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `s/n` is in A1 of your `!st` sheet and `Name` in A1 of your second sheet,  in B2 of your second sheet and copied across to suit:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(first.$B1:$B99;$A2;first.$C1:$C99;"<="&B$1;first.$D1:$D99;">="&B$1)=0;"";COUNTIFS(first.$B1:$B99;$A2;first.$C1:$C99;"<="&B$1;first.$D1:$D99;">="&B$1))
```